# Two ng-click, two class different in ng-repeat depending option clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have two buttons which should remove a div on a ng-repeat, but depending on the button must add a custom css class to the effect, depending on the option the css changes.

If I click on the button should be added on the first card class either reject or accept and remove the card, right now I'm removing the card through .pop () but not adds class. if I delete $scope.matches.pop(); adds class but obviously do not delete the card, if I keep that line, do not add the css class.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/go54DQMsPdsRcssLeZZ5?p=preview

I'm using the following code:

```
<td-card ng-class="{reject : rejectShow(match), accept : acceptShow(match)}" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" class="cards card-{{$index}}" > 
    <div class="content">content</div>
</td>

<button class="button" ng-click="reject(match)">
    button reject
</button>

<button class="button" ng-click="accept(match)">
    button accept
</button>
```

Code AngularJS:

```
var shownAccept = false
var shownReject = false
var className = 'initClass';

$scope.accept = function(match) {
    console.log('accept button')
    $scope.matches.pop();
    shownAccept = match;
}

$scope.reject = function(match) {
    console.log('reject button')
    $scope.matches.pop();
    shownReject = match;
}

$scope.rejectShow = function(match) {
    return angular.equals(shownReject, match);
}

$scope.acceptShow = function(match) {
    return angular.equals(shownAccept, match);
}
```

PS. I'm looking for options that do not use jquery

Comment: Do you want to keep row as is instead of deleting it & you want to add accept & reject class on button click? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I want to delete an item from the list and when removing add this class, the following items are kept and the following items are not added until the class is eliminated one by one.

Comment: really I don't get you please can you add fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: It looks like this, in this case by having the .pop () classes not printed on the item disappears http://plnkr.co/edit/go54DQMsPdsRcssLeZZ5?p=preview

Comment: @yorchp please refer my plunkr below in comments on my answer. if there are any changes plz provide another plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable `$scope.selectedIndex`

Whenever you click update: `$scope.selectedIndex = $index`

Comment: Thanks, an example of how it could be applied?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/f8TyKRijOwVFkbC9nJTS?p=preview
It would be better if you have a plunkr already created.

Comment: It looks like this, in this case by having the .pop () classes not printed on the item disappears http://plnkr.co/edit/go54DQMsPdsRcssLeZZ5?p=preview

Comment: you are poping items, without index. i did not get that part. you can `splice` array.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ro5MLUuWXPif1eLYlwd5?p=preview